# Is immediate mode OpenGL guaranteed to work on modern hardware, even though it's deprecated?

Tags: opengl, opengl-compat, immediate-mode

I'm maintaining a legacy application which uses OpenGL for rendering.

The application works well on each workstation even though it relies on the deprecated immediate mode. However, should the workstations' hardware be replaced with modern counterparts, is the application guaranteed to work as expected?

Porting the application to modern OpenGL is not acceptable at this point due to code complexity and time constraints.

Minor performance losses are acceptable and expected, since newer hardware may be optimized for OpenGL's retained mode.

Is this application going to work on modern machines?

Comment: In so far vendors still keep legacy OGL in their drivers. I doubt they will remove it. If you were a vendor, would you force so many existing apps to move expensively (develop, check, fix bugs, etc) to a new version, in return for nothing?

Comment: @TomBombadil: No, Quads and Polygons have not been removed from legacy GL.

Comment: Oh alright my bad, gonna delete my comment then